# My telegram bot which recives an image from camera with opencv gives me an error and doesn't work

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-tesseract, opencv

I can not understand why it is not working. Most of the time it returns error or just does not entering the for loop. I honestly don't know why.

importing libraries and defining variables

```
import telebot  
import paho.mqtt as mqtt  
from time import *  
import pytesseract  
from paho.mqtt import client as mqtt  
import socket   
import cv2
import numpy  
from PIL import Image    
message_bot = ''  
is_ready = False  
on_point_4 = False  
start_charge = False  
last_message = ''  
bot_message = ''  
last_x_coordinate = 0  
last_y_coordinate = 0  
charge_stoped = False  
on_message function
def on_message(client, userdata, message):  
    message_from_bot = message.payload.decode()  
    global charge_stoped  
    print(message_from_bot)  
    if message_from_bot == 'ok':  
        is_ready = True  
        last_message = message_from_bot  
        print(is_ready)  
    if len(message_from_bot) >= 6:  
        message_from_bot = message_from_bot.split('"')  
        bot_message = message_from_bot[3]  
        bot_message = bot_message.lower()  
        print(bot_message)
```

tesseract

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:/Program Files/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe'
```

telegram bot token

```
# bot connect  
token = '****'  
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)
```

mqtt connect

```
hostname = "mqtt.pi40.ru"  
port = 1883  
username = "****"  
password = "****"  
clientID = "nvjrfhruhnv"   
client = mqtt.Client('****')  
client.subscribe('***/charge_stoped')  
client.username_pw_set(***, password)  
client.connect(hostname, port)
```

cascade

```
cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_russian_plate_number.xml')
```

another variables

```
user_message = ''  
image = 0  
gray = 0  
plates = ''  
result = ''
```

beggining of the bot

```
# start of the bot  
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])  
def send_welcome(message):   
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     f'Добро пожаловать на Enegry Parking! \nВведите пожалуйста номер своей машины латинскими буквами, {message.from_user.first_name}')
```

image reciving function

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])  
def recieve_photo(message_photo):  
    global plates  
    global gray  
    photo_id = message_photo.photo[-1].file_id  
    file_info = bot.get_file(photo_id)  
    downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)  
    with open("image.jpg", 'wb') as new_file:  
        new_file.write(downloaded_file)  
    image = cv2.imread('image.jpg')  
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  
    plates = cascade.detectMultiScale(gray)
```

from user input function and comparing to the carnumber detected on image using khar cascade

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])  
def send_reply(message):  
    global start_charge  
    global last_x_coordinate  
    global last_y_coordinate  
    if message.text.lower() != '' and len(message.text.lower()) >= 6:  
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,
        'Спасибо, в скором времени начнется зарядка вашего эллектромобиля \nМы оповестим вас о завершении загрузки.')  
        # user_message = str(message.text.lower())  
        for plate in plates:  
            x, y, w, h = plate  
        centreX = int((x + (x + w)) / 2)  
        centreY = int((y + (y + h)) / 2)  
        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 255), 10)  
        crop = gray[y:y + h, x:x + w]  
        # value, mask = cv2.threshold(crop, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)  
        # cv2.imshow('window_mask', mask)  
        text2 = pytesseract.image_to_string(crop, lang='eng')  
        print(text2)  
        if len(text2) >= 6 and text2 != '':  
            getVals = list([val for val in text2  
                            if val.isalpha() or val.isnumeric()])  

            text2 = "".join(getVals)  
            text2 = text2.lower()  
            text2 = text2[0:6]  
            print(text2)  
            print('readed')
```

sending messages to mqtt and ending the program later

```
        if charge_stoped == False:  
            if text2 == message.text.lower()[0:6] and len(text2) >= 6:  
                print("readed")  
                if centreX != last_x_coordinate:  
                    client.publish("****/centreX_plate", centreX)  
                    last_x_coordinate = centreX  
                    print("Angle carnum Sent")  
                if centreY != last_y_coordinate:  
                    client.publish("****/centreY_plate", centreY)  
                    last_y_coordinate = centreY  
                    print("dist carnume sent")  
                start_charge = True  

            client.publish("****/start_charge", start_charge)  
            start_charge = False  
        else:  
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Зарядка была успешно произведена!\nХорошего вам дня!')  

    else:  
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Простите, но номер машины должен иметь минимум из 6 символов.')  
    print(message.text.lower()[0:6])  

print('До свидания!')  
bot.polling(none_stop=True)  
client.loop_forever()
```

Comment: What's the error and where? That's a lot of code to go through.

Comment: It says what:
 centreX = int((x + (x + w)) / 2)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment

Comment: but sometimes it just skips the part with scaning and doesnt work

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: it seems you use variable `x` which doesn't have value

Comment: you create `x` in code `for plate in plates:  x, y, w, h = plate` but if `plates` is empty then it doesn't create `x` but you try to use `x` in next lines. As for me you have wrong indentations and you should run next lines inside `for`-loop.

Comment: Well, when i'm doing this, code just does not working, it looks like it skips this lines and gives no output from them

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in your `send_reply` function, in particular in this section of code:

```py
        for plate in plates:  
            x, y, w, h = plate  
        centreX = int((x + (x + w)) / 2)
```

You are declaring x, y, w and h inside the for loop, those variables therefore will only be available inside that loop.

I am not sure what you want to do exactly with your code but probably you should have all the code inside the for loop.